# Recursive CTE possible for this?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, recursion, common-table-expression

I have product data structured in the following format:

```
ProductID   OptionID    Lvl OptionDescription   SubOptionID SubOptionDescription
HPH 6   1   Model   10  Studio
HPH 6   1   Model   11  DJ
HPH 7   2   Device  12  Bluetooth
HPH 7   2   Device  13  Cable
HPH 7   2   Device  14  Remote
```

There could be any number of levels to the product. I need to traverse the hierarchy and produce the following output - a description for each product option:

```
Studio-Bluetooth
Studio-Cable
Studio-Remote
DJ-Bluetooth
DJ-Cable
DJ-Remote
```

I've looked CTE's but the examples tend to incorporate adjacent lists (employeeID; managerID..etc) which don't seem appropriate here.

How can I achieve this output?

Thanks.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Products](
    [ProductID] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [OptionID] [int] NULL,
    [Lvl] [int] NULL,
    [OptionDescription] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [SubOptionID] [int] NULL,
    [SubOptionDescription] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

insert into Products (ProductID, OptionID, Lvl, OptionDescription, SubOptionID,    SubOptionDescription) values ('HPH', 6, 1, 'Model', 10, 'Studio')
insert into Products (ProductID, OptionID, Lvl, OptionDescription, SubOptionID, SubOptionDescription) values ('HPH', 6, 1, 'Model', 11, 'DJ')
insert into Products (ProductID, OptionID, Lvl, OptionDescription, SubOptionID, SubOptionDescription) values ('HPH', 7, 2, 'Device', 12, 'Bluetooth')
insert into Products (ProductID, OptionID, Lvl, OptionDescription, SubOptionID, SubOptionDescription) values ('HPH', 7, 2, 'Device', 13, 'Cable')
insert into Products (ProductID, OptionID, Lvl, OptionDescription, SubOptionID, SubOptionDescription) values ('HPH', 7, 2, 'Device', 14, 'Remote')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with cte as (
    -- Root level
    select p.Lvl, cast(p.SubOptionDescription as varchar(max)) as [ProductOption]
    from @Products p where p.Lvl = 1
    union all
    -- Anchor part - cartesian here?
    select p.Lvl, c.ProductOption + '-' + p.SubOptionDescription
    from @Products p
        inner join cte c on c.Lvl = p.Lvl - 1
)
select c.ProductOption from cte c;
```

A couple of notes.

Right now your sample answer implies that you need to create a cartesian product. I hope this is not the case, because the amount of rows will increase explosively. If there are other join conditions which are not apparent from your sample, you can introduce them in the anchor part of the CTE.

You would probably also want to return only leaf rows. There are several ways to do it - there may be some attribute in your actual data, or a combination of `rank()` and `top (1) with ties` will do the trick, although it won't be particularly efficient.